# import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, next.js

**My Goal is** get data from json file
`import { promises as fs } from "fs";`

```
export default async function Header() {
  const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/app/lang.json", "utf8");
  const data = JSON.parse(file);

  const navigation = [
    { name: arLang ? data.ar.about : data.en.about, href: "#X" },
    { name: arLang ? data.ar.pricing : data.en.pricing, href: "#X" },
    { name: arLang ? data.ar.contact : data.en.contact, href: "#X" },
  ];
```

it is a component for header i use in my website to switch language so how to solve this problem or there's another method i should do to get the data from the json file to display it in my page ?

i tried to do it with object in my files but i couldn't use components bcs i couldn't make a switch lang change the status in the main lang file to switch between languages to set the AR or EN status

**So i need help or a solution to solve this or another method to use to do this task please**

**Still a Junior :(**

Comment: your code is incomplete ... sure, you've created `const navigation` ... but then do nothing with it, perhaps that's the problem

Comment: "*it is a component for header i use in my website*" - are you saying this code is supposed to run in a browser? It won't! `fs` is a nodejs module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to access node functions inside of a component that is meant to be rendered in a browser. Fetching files that exist in the server using node APIs is the job of a server component, so you may want to look into that instead.

You could also, alternatively, set up an API to fetch the file if it's dynamic or just make it statically available for the website to fetch using the JavaScript fetch API. Heck, you could even just import the file directly and most bundlers will handle asset management for you.